# Intent Service persist with low memory

Tags: android, android-service, android-memory, android-intentservice

How to persist the `Intent Service` at the time when system memory is not allowing to execute the `Intent Service`.

Comment: You may wish to explain, in greater detail, what you mean. An `IntentService` is designed to run for a handful of seconds, then shut down when its work is complete. What "system memory" conditions are preventing you from calling `startService()` on this `IntentService`? What does it mean to "persist" an `IntentService`?

Comment: when android runs on low memory would kill other apps/services so whenever you run ur service normally there should be some memory for execution. if you can elaborate a bit on what your service does on the background? how much memory it would need roughly?

Comment: @CommonsWare actually we are performing amazon file upload operation via intent service, based on amazon code. But in meantime when system founds less memory space then it frees up all the resources and in this way, our work gets affected. so by persistence we mean that if in case any such thing happen then we should do some operation before halting the service.

Comment: hi eldjon, since its a file upload operation so we can't judge in advance that how much memory is required for such operation. Is there any way to resolve it or to find a way?

Comment: what do you use for uploading the file? can you post the code/

Comment: I used this https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-simpl3r link as reference to upload file on amazon via Multipart.

Answer (score 0):

You cant.

There is not enough memory to run your code.

Comment: How can i handle this...because it cause crash to my application.

Comment: check the available memory before attempting to execute your code. Wrap it in a try catch. Lots of things that are very dependent on your code.